# CSS for disabling clicks for a particular component using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components, inline

```
<RowContainer style={isPlayerTurn ? {pointer-events: 'auto'} : {pointerEvents: 'none'}}>
```

How do I disable a user from clicking the RowContainer component when isPlayerTurn=False? Is it pointer-events(VSC giving me a ',' expected error) or pointerEvents?

Both don't seem to work as of now as user can still click on the component.

Update:
RowContainer is a component I created:

```
    import styled from "styled-components";
    const RowContainer = styled.div`
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    `;
```

Here is what my `RowContainer` is wrapping:

```
            <RowContainer style={isPlayerTurn ? {pointerEvents: 'auto'} : pointerEvents: 'none'}>
              {row.map((column, columnIdx) => (
                <Cell
                  className={styles.cell}
                  borderRight={columnIdx < 2}
                  borderLeft={columnIdx > 0}
                  borderBottom={rowIdx < 2}
                  borderTop={rowIdx > 0}
                  onClick={() =>
                    updateGameMatrix(columnIdx, rowIdx, playerSymbol)
                  }
                >
                  {column && column !== "" ? (
                    column === "x" ? (
                      <X />
                    ) : (
                      <O />
                    )
                  ) : null}
                </Cell>
              ))}
            </RowContainer>
```

Comment: pointerEvents should work. Please share more code or a codesandbox link preferably

Comment: What is `RowContainer` from? Does it accept a `style`?

Comment: perhaps use `'pointer-events'`